# What's the license of the web video/audio player of mediaelement.js?

Tags: mediaelement.js

Here is the github location:
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement

and their website:
http://mediaelementjs.com/

I wanna deploy it but I have no idea what the license is, or the commercial fee.

Comment: Make sure to hit the green checkmark if you like the answer. You get points too

Answer (score 3):

It says it right there on the github README: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement

> License: GPLv2/MIT
>
> Meaning: Please use this everywhere and it'd be
> swell if you'd link back here.

In case you want even more info about a MIT license: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License